# Frozen objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

In Ruby, what does it mean for a `String` or `Array` (etc) object to be 'Frozen'? How/where is this property set or modified?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means you cannot modify it. You set it by `freeze` method.

```
s = "a"
```

`concat` modifies the string instance.

```
s.concat("b")
# => "ab"
```

When you freeze the string:

```
s.freeze
```

then, you cannot apply `concat` any more.

```
s.concat("c")
# => RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
```

However, you can apply methods that do not modify the receiver:

```
s + "c"
# => "abc"
```

Answer (score 2):

Prevents further modifications to obj. A RuntimeError will be raised if modification is attempted. There is no way to unfreeze a frozen object. See also Object#frozen?.

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
a.freeze
a << "z"
```

produces:

```
prog.rb:3:in `<<': can't modify frozen array (RuntimeError)
from prog.rb:3
```

[Doco](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-freeze)